# Flutter: How to find location for error, Build error, Not found: 'dart:html'?

Tags: flutter, dart-html

I know this is due to some web libraries accidentally imported to the mobile section, but where? There's no file or code line is mentioned within the project which is causing the issue. My project is very huge with a lot of dependencies. I have both mobile and web-specific code files separately. I think I have mixed at any point and now unable to find the location where's it happening.

Any method to figure it out? Is there any method to specifically debug the file which is causing the error??

```
    ../../../../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.2/lib/src/top_level.dart:1:8: Error: Not found: 'dart:html'
    import 'dart:html';
           ^
```

Comment: which editor are you using ?

Comment: if android studio, `ctrl` + `shit` + `r` press this combination. Then type `import 'dart:html';` in the search bar. You'll find the location.

Comment: Android studio, Yeah I do have `import 'dart:html' ` but that's required for some functions to run for web. I just wanna know where's this clash?

Answer (score 0):

dart:html is only for web and since you cannot build apk or ios with it due to its hinderance and also want to use it due to web,so  I would suggest you another solution which works perfectly.

Use [universal_html](https://pub.dev/packages/universal_html) : A 'dart:html' that works in all platforms, including Flutter and server-side. Eases cross-platform development and HTML / XML processing.

```
dependencies:
universal_html: ^2.0.8
```

Replace `import 'dart:html' as html;`
with

```
import 'package:universal_html/html.dart' as html;
```

Comment: This is becoming a bigger issue. More and more web packages are using it and to be able to offer all platforms, it is essential this works for all platforms. Right now all the searches suggest using universal_html which i've done in my app, but the dependencies need to adopt it to I think. For example, this from my latest flutter run on a Samsung device: flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/image_picker_web-2.0.3+1/lib/src/extensions/file_extensions.dart:2:8: Error: Not found: 'dart:html'. Do we need to go through every library, or is this up to the individual developers of the packages?